# Display word count in modeline without lag

Tags: init-file, mode-line, words, counter

### Problem

Stopped using `wc-mode` as it is not snappy anymore (as text writing usually is) with text document of 10k words. It appears that it *counts the whole buffer after every change* which seems to make it slow as logged [here](https://github.com/bnbeckwith/wc-mode/issues/13). A recent change was made to speed it up, but still produces considerable lag.

### Partial Solution

There is a "solution" [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29198/17941), but it is so hard for me to implement it as I am not familiar with Lisp and inner workings of Emacs. There are two functions `wc-buffer` and `wc-region`, which are empty in the answer (below), for which I have no clue what should be in the function.

```lisp
;; Function that counts words in buffer
(defun wc-buffer ()
  ...)

;; Function that counts words in a region
(defun wc-region (rbeg rend)
  ...)
    
(defvar-local a1 nil)
(defvar-local a2 nil)
(defvar-local curr-wc nil)
    
(defun init-function ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (setq curr-wc (wc-buffer))))

(defun wc-update-before (change-beg change-end)
  (setq pos1 (max 1 (1- change-beg)))
  (setq pos2 (min (point-max) (1+ change-end)))
    
  (setq a1 (wc-region pos1 pos2)))
    
(defun wc-update-after (change-beg change-end prev-len)
  (if (bound-and-true-p a1) 
      (progn
        (setq pos1 (max 1 (1- change-beg)))
        (setq pos2 (min (point-max) (1+ change-end)))
            
        (setq a2 (wc-region pos1 pos2))
            
        (setq curr-wc (+ curr-wc (- a2 a1))))
      nil))

(init-function)
(add-hook 'before-change-functions #'wc-update-before nil t) 
(add-hook 'after-change-functions #'wc-update-after nil t)
(setq inhibit-modification-hooks nil)
```

### Help

I ask for someone either to tell me explicitly what goes in these functions or suggest alternatives for counting words and not having lag while displaying them in the mode-line.

### Reproducing

You can reproduce this by: installing `wc-mode` and enabling it and then when you have more than 10k words, you can expect (depending on your PC) quite some lag while typing. It's not snappy.

Comment: This sounds like a "please code something for me" pseudo-question - it lacks focus. What exactly is the question/problem? What does "lagged the hell out of my..." really mean? Please show your code - minimal recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). Thx.

Comment: For time consuming functions that I use to obtain certain data for the mode-line (e.g., alphabetizing minor-mode lighter indicators), I use a two-step approach to deal with that:  (1) record the most recent value and reuse that recorded value when certain criteria is met, instead of calculating anew; (2), if `this-command` is `eq` to `last-command` and the command is a `memq` of a predefined list of certain commands, then use the pre-recorded value from step 1 above.  Flyspell uses step 2 if you are interested in seeing how that works.

Comment: @drew I have edited the question to make it more clear. Please let me know if this is good enough?

Comment: Much better, thanks. It still looks like a request to code up some functions, and it requires turning to another question for understanding. Can you show the code you tried, and pose a specific question about that, and can you make this question more standalone? This site is really better for specific Q&A, not discussion. You might want to post this more open-ended question on a site such as Reddit, where discussion etc. is invited.

Comment: @drew modified the question added code from the linked answer. No, I don't want to post it on reddit, I want direction in which I need to go. I want a solution. I will try using the suggestions provided by user12593215 and figure out how to implient it in the modeline I guess.

Comment: @lawlist I will check out how flyspell is written in case the answer provided by user12593215 doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**, add `(setq wc-idle-wait 2)` into `~/.emacs` if you need get updated with the data in real time,

[image]

Please note `wc-idle-wait` should be set **before** loading `wc-mode.el` because of below code in `wc-mode.el`,

```
(setq wc-timer-tracker
      (run-with-idle-timer
       wc-idle-wait t
       '(lambda ()
          (when wc-mode
            (setq wc-buffer-stats (wc-mode-update))))))
```

**Solution 2**, do the calculation only before saving current buffer. But you need set `wc-idle-wait` to a bigger value first.

Here is sample setup (see my comment, you can do some further optimization inside `before-save-hook`),

```
(setq wc-idle-wait most-positive-fixnum)
(add-hook 'before-save-hook
          (lambda ()
            ;; you can check `buffer-file-name' or `major-mode' first
            (setq wc-buffer-stats (wc-mode-update))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `count-words` to implement the `wc-buffer` function and `count-words-region` to implement the `wc-region` function.

Like this:

```lisp
(defun wc-buffer ()
    (count-words (point-min) (point-max)))

(defun wc-region (rbeg rend)
    (count-words-region rbeg rend))
```

Comment: I wonder if we even need these two functions. the `count-words` scope is already the whole buffer and the `count-words-region` returns the word and character count of the marked region. so imho these functions are redundant. That said, +1 for mentioning these two builtin functions.

Answer (score 0):

See [mode-line-idle](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-mode-line-idle/), the `readme` shows an example of showing a word count in a way that's not blocking.

This allows you to add anything you like to your mode line in a way that doesn't block your workflow.